# Retrieve specific row on a datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagridview, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I have a wpf Datagrid which displays some informations about remote hard disks. I want to colorize a row when disk space is under a certain treshold.

Here is how I get my results in the C# code :

```
    public void FillDataGridView(DataGrid datagrid)
    {
        for (var i=0; i < hList.Count; i++)
        {
            double value = Convert.ToDouble(hList[i].Libre.Substring(0,5));

            if (value < 5) // For example
            {
                // Retrieve intended row, and colorize it to Red 
            }
            else
            {
                // Retrieve intended row, and colorize it to Green
            }
        }
        datagrid.ItemsSource = hList;
    }
```

"value" is a double like that : 29,22.

In my datagrid, I have as mucg rows as hdd on remote computer. I tried some things, but it always colorize the whole datagrid.

Is anyone could help me ?
If I missed some details, feel free to let me know.

EDIT

[[Here is the grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLfKM.png)]

If for example the C drive have less than 5 Go, I want to color that row in red.
Thank's :)

Comment: My datagrid contains 1 row per disks found, and some columns (volume name, total space, free space, etc). If the freespace available is under a certain treshold, i want to colorize that row in red.

Comment: The comment in your case says "Retrieve intended row". So again, what is the "intended" row?

Comment: oh sorry :) it's the row where the cell's value (in the "free space" column) is less than "5" (in my example). If it is not clear enough, i will try to update my post, and add a screenshot

Comment: That sounds like a good plan.